# Compute the curveintegral $\int_\gamma x(4x^2+4y+1) \ dx+16y \ dy.$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, proof-verification

> Compute the curveintegral $$I=\int_\gamma x(4x^2+4y+1) \ dx+16y \ dy,$$
>
> where $\gamma$ is the part of the curve
>   $\left(4x^2+4y^2\right)^2=-x^2+16$ positioned in the right hemisphere
>   going from the point $[0,-1]$ to $[0,1].$

So I have that $(P,Q)=(4x^3+4xy+x,16y),$ parametrizing by

$$\left\{
  \begin{array}{rcr}
    x & = & \cos{t} \\
    y & = & \sin{t} \\
  \end{array}
\right. \implies\left\{
  \begin{array}{rcr}
    dx & = & -\sin{t} \\
    dy & = & \cos{t} \\
  \end{array}
\right., \quad t\in[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$$

so using $I=\int_\gamma Pdx+Qdy$ I get

$$I=\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}(-4\cos^3{t}\sin{t}-4\sin^2{t}\cos{t}-\cos{t}\sin{t}+16\sin{t}\cos{t}) \ dt = 0-\frac{8}{3}+0=-\frac{8}{3}.$$

Is this correct?

Comment: This is not an ellipse in $x$-$y$ plane, but in $x^2$-$y^2$ plane it is.

Comment: I'll update my question. This is part of a larger problem.